# Adobe Illustrator: How to build a color palette around skin tone

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-theory

I'm using Adobe Illustrator and the recolor dialog box. For the purpose of this artwork, I can't change the skin tone, and the color of the hair is also limited. I'd like for Illustrator to give me a selection of color harmonies while keeping the skin tone fixed.  How can this be done?

[image]

ps. As a secondary question, when I enter recolor edit, one circle is much bigger than the others.  I guess this must be in some way the "dominant" color.  But if you look at my picture, this dominant color is a small percentage of the art.  Shouldn't  Illustrator use the total area of each color to figure the dominant color?

Appendum: As Scott points out, large circle is the "base" color.  It is used as a reference for the color harmonies, as seen in the second screenshot.

Appendum: To change the base color, one suggestion is to click on a color in the top bar. This does appear to change the base color as indicated by the arrow, in the third screenshot. However, the base color in the harmonies is not changes. I would submit this is actually a bug in the software.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Big circle is just the selected color click on any other circle.

Comment: @joojaa I didn't seem to work for me.  When I click on other circles, the big one stays the biggest.  I learned something.  When I change color harmony in the Recolor Dialog box, the color in the big circle stays fixed. Now if I could get the big circle to be the skin tone, my problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The large circle designates the "base color", which will control global saturation and value for all the colors when the colors are locked. It has *nothing* to do with the *actual* color in the circle.

With **locked colors** in `Edit` mode, you can drag any *small* circle inward/outward to change the saturation/value of just that color.

But if you drag the base color circle in/out, you change saturation/value for *all colors*.

[image]

Rotating around the wheel with any circle will edit all colors when colors are locked. The big circle does not indicate any "frozen" or "don't edit" color. Even if the base color were the skin tone, that would not keep hues from changing if rotated around the wheel.

To **change the base color**, and make harmonies start from a new base color, **right-click** (control-click) any color circle on the wheel and choose `set as base color` from the popup contextual menu.

[image]

---

You can't really "freeze" colors in illustrator with any of the edit colors features. You can merely *not touch* the skin tones and assign new colors to other indicators. But in general there's no "freeze" or "don't alter" for individual colors in color editing features (other than black and white).

**However**, if you **lock** the **objects in the art**, before selecting and calling Recolor Artwork, they won't be part of the selection and thus not part of any recoloring.

So, on the artboard, select and **lock** (`Object > Lock`) all shapes/objects which are colored with skin tones. Then you can select all and recolor, locked objects *won't* be selected and therefore *not* recolored.

Alternatively you can merely *not select* skin tone objects before calling Recolor Artwork.

Recolor artwork will only recolor what is *selected*.

Comment: I gave your very nice response a thumbs up.  However, it leaves so many open questions.   One question is this: Are you saying that the hue of the big circle is entirely arbitrary?  I don't think it is arbitrary, so how does Illutrator determine the hue of the big circle?  Illustrator apparently think the hue of the big circle is important because it bases all the color harmonies on it. See the new picture I added to my questions.

Comment: @Chris Illustrator sees the hue of the big circle as "base" for some reason. I honestly don't know what that algorithm is. It may be something like most prolific color, or most common color values, or average values. My point was that the hue of the big circle is not really imperative to the wheel other than when it's moves with locked colors. It's **only** big to show the user which circle will change global values as in the animation above. If you click *anywhere* in the color bar across the top, then circle highlight changes, making whatever color you clicked the new *base* color.

Comment: I honestly don't know *how* AI chooses the base color. I think it would take an AI dev to weigh in on that since I can't find, and have never seen any information regarding that specifically. However, overall, it's really not that important which color is set as "base" it's not "locked" or unchangeable. Note the "base" color is also the first color at the top of the Assign tab.

Comment: @Chris all mathematical operations on color are somewhat arbitrary. Mainly because the true science behind color vision is, "Rocket science". Hell we do not even have consensus on what the color wheel should look like ergo rotating around hue **is arbitrary**. But yes the entire UI of the recolor artwork dialog is,perplexing and arbitrarily over complex. But at the same time totally under developped for most usecases.

Comment: @Scott   I take your point that the big circle on the wheel is different that the smaller circles in that when you move it, you are changing the global value of saturation.  Where I disagree is when you say that "it's really not important which color is set as 'base'".   I submit it is important because the color harmonies created by the recolor dialog box all hold the base constant.    Therefore, if I could equate the base color to skin tone, I would be able to look at the color harmonies built around skin tone

Comment: It would not be hard for Illustrator to let us change the base color.   However, I did not find any way to do this within the Recolor dialog box.  On the other hand, in the color guide dialog box you can change the base color. The color guide dialog box might answer my question.  I'm going to write up an answer later today.

Comment: @Chris.. click a color in the bar at the top.. that changes the base color for harmonies.. it *doesn't* change the big circle though. It *does* move the highlight to the color you click.

Comment: @Scott  When I click a color at the bar at the top, it does appear to change the base colors, but it isn't applied to the harmonies. I will add a screenshot to show this to my question.

Comment: @Chris see answer update... all this is covered in [Illustrator's Help files](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/color-basics.html)

Comment: @Scott    I tried this:   I clicked on a skin tone circle in the color wheel. I selected "set as base color".  As you suggest, the skin tone color which I selected is now the base color.  All the harmonies are now based on this new base color, as  is appropriate.   However, when I clicked on "set as base color" it also changed every color in the artwork.   I can't explain the logic of these changes.    In any case, I would suggest that setting a new base color should not change the artwork.   Would you agree?  Have you tried this "set as base color" command?

Comment: Honestly, I think you may be expecting too much automation here. I don't really rely on any app to choose colors for me. To each their own though. I don't think you'll *ever* get quality results expecting the app to just pick harmonies for you. It can't *see* the artwork. It's akin to a someone expecting to write a great song by letting some app just randomly pick music scales.

Comment: @Scott I agree with you.  I am probably obsessed with this issue.  Actually, I have found that there is a way to accomplish my goal with the color guide dialog box.  However, at this point, I'm trying to get to the bottom of this bug in the recolor dialog box.  My claim is that you should be able to select a new base color without changing the artwork.  Would you agree with that statement?

Comment: The number of things one "should be able to do" in Illustrator is endless. All apps have limitations - Adobe limitations are most often due to the accounting department not allocating dollars for dev time. New features make money, not fully fleshed out features.

Comment: @Chris There comes a time when you realize that adobe does regularily release features that are entirely garbage. You just learn to ignore them. Adobe, with exception of After effects and Indesign team never do retakes of released designs. Once they have shipped a tool thats it they will never do anything about it. The only reason they do a fix is if it breaks other exsiting tools. So no as far as adobe is concerned its not a bug but a feature, atleast its not as annoying as the perspective grid tool.

Comment: Well, the Adobe AI team will *add* to a feature, but you're right, they don't really go backwards and change or fix anything they've already done unless there's a fatal issue (ie crash) associated with a feature. They have added to Live Color in the last couple releases with the "theme" stuff... but, well, I think usage for that is a very niche market. I could be wrong though. -- and yeah.. what a total waste the perspective grid is, at least here.

Comment: Well lets see... The new 3D is comming.

Comment: Well.. that *was* the reason they *thought* the Perspective Grid was needed. So yeah, we'll see. Of course I have to purchase a new system before I'll see anything `:)`